# How to make parent window accept focus/close only if child window is closed

Tags: c++, qt

I want the parent window to accept focus or be able to be closed only if the child window that is opened is closed. Just like how the option action in the tools menu of Qt Creator behaves when it is opened
The code;

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

#include "childwindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void openChildWindow();

private:

    QPushButton *button;

    ChildWindow *childWindow;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {

    button = new QPushButton("Go");

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button);

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openChildWindow()));

    setLayout(layout);
}

void MainWindow::openChildWindow() {
    childWindow = new ChildWindow;
    childWindow->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {

}
```

childwindow.h

```
#ifndef CHILDWINDOW_H
#define CHILDWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>

class ChildWindow : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ChildWindow();
    ~ChildWindow();
};

#endif // CHILDWINDOW_H
```

childwindow.cpp

```
#include "childwindow.h"

ChildWindow::ChildWindow() {

}

ChildWindow::~ChildWindow() {

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow *window = new MainWindow;
    window->showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```

How do i go about it?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a modal dialog? You're already using a QDialog as the base class anyway.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer and accept it? This way it is clearly visible that your problem is solved http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Timo Geusch should provide it as an answer so i accept it